# Number of 9 binary (0 or 1) dgits is chosen at random with all 2^9 equal probability

Tags: probability, combinatorics

**A number of 9 binary digits (0 or 1) is chosen at random with all 2^9 possible results having equal probability. Let X be the random variable equal to the number of times 010 appears in the string. What is the expectation of X?**

So i understand how to do expectations, the part I'm having trouble on is finding the probabilities.

Do i find the probability of getting a 0 then a 1 then back to a 0 out of 9 digits?
9C1 9C1 9C1?

Answer (score 1):

### Hint

For $i=1\ldots 7$ define a random variable $X_i$ as follows: $X_i=1$ if the random string contains the sequence $010$ starting at the $i$'th digit, and $X_i=0$ otherwise.

Note that $X=X_1+\ldots+X_7$ and use linearity of expectations.